# how to add autoincrement column in mongodb with typeorm

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

i am using nestjs and trying to add an auto Increment column by typeorm and mongodb driver but nothing happed and also the column not created
and that is my commands

```
import { Column, Entity, Generated, ObjectIdColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({name : 'employees'})
export class Employees {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    id : string  
    
    @Column({type : 'string'})
    userName : string 
    
    @Column({type : 'string'})
    fullName : string 

    @Column()
    @Generated('increment')
    employeeID : string
```

is that feature available in mongodb or only mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not support auto-increment.

Comment: @KamalRadwan Hope this what you want https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: thank you but i switched to mariadb for now and later i will check it